# Functions get Remove when zip deploy function app using Azure CLI or PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-deployment

I'm facing an issue while deploying the azure function using Azure CLI or Azure PowerShell.

I have already created needed resources like resource group, function app and blob storage.

My function app platform type is **Linux** with consumption plan and runtime net6.0. I have created Service Bus trigger function and deployed using Visual Studio Publish profile and it is working as expected.

But when I executed the command to deploy the Azure function using CLI. Command is executing successfully but when I open the function app from azure portal and go to functions blade the deployed functions do not appear there.

I also checked the folder structure of the build output as mentioned in the link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Reproduced the same issue from our end using Az-CLI**

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <Resource Group> -n <Function App Name> --src <Function Project with Zip>
```

[image]

[image]

---

#### Workaround to fix the issue

After setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` to `true` in Configuration > Application Settings of the Azure Function App in Portal and deployed again using `AZ CLI` commands and shown the functions in Portal and in Kudu site of `wwwroot` folder.

[image]

**AZ CLI Command:**

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g HariTestRG -n KrishNet6FuncApp --src "C:/Users/Hari/source/repos/DotNet6/TimerTrigger1205.zip"
```

[image]

According to this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#deployment-customization), we came to know that some deployment customization has to be done before deploying the Function App as a Zip Push, i.e., by default the app setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` is false which enables the continuous integration deployment.

For the PowerShell Workaround, refer [GitHub Page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#sample-of-using-rest-api-with-powershell).

Comment: Is your function app platform type Linux or windows?

Comment: I think your function app platform type is windows otherwise kudu console does not support linux.

Comment: yes, it is windows platform.

Comment: @DelliganeshS-MT your answer will definitely help to function app issues with platform type windows. but it does not help for platform type linux.  anyway, thanks.

Comment: @UmairAbid, Refer [here](https://help.octopus.com/t/deploy-azure-function-app-to-linux-consumption-plan/24550)

Answer (score 0):

Function App running on Linux OS in consumption plan has limited deployment options but supports only remote build.

To enable remote build on Linux, the following application settings must be set:

```
ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD=true
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true
```

> If your project needs to use remote build, don't use the
> **WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE** app setting.

Functions Core Tools is the only **solution** work for me.
By default, Azure Functions Core Tool perform remote builds when deploying to Linux. Because of this, it automatically create these settings for you in Azure.

```
func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName>
```

my custom script file

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
$AppName,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
$LocalProjectPath
)

cd "$($LocalProjectPath)"

func azure functionapp publish $AppName

cd ..
```

if you need more help with **Linux hosting** use this link [Zip Deploymnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies) to get detailed information related to **Azure Functions Deployments**.